Flutter app not compiling because some lib is expecting SDK 35?
I am receiving this error (error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowOptOutEdgeToEdgeEnforcement' not found.) while building my app, seems image_cropper is expecting target sdk to be 35, while I have latest Flutter update which seems using Android SDK 35, what shall I do?
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:D:\myproject\build\image_cropper\intermediates\packaged_res\debug\values-v35\values-v35.xml:3:5-5:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowOptOutEdgeToEdgeEnforcement' not found.

while my config in build.gradle is, which seems using Android SDK 35 :
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion

And my Flutter version is :
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.27.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.26100.2605], locale en-US)


Please share your flutter configuration file so we can see what the value of flutter.targetSdkVersion is. Also, the error you shared doesn't talk about API 35, but rather a style attribute not being found. Your pubspec.yaml can also help.

image_cropper 8.1.0 adds windowOptOutEdgeToEdgeEnforcement which is only in API 35. It looks like somewhere the build is defaulting to API 34.
Check the ext setting in android/build.gradle (or other build settings that may be overriding the compileSdk)
e.g.
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "35.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 28
    compileSdkVersion   = 35                // or higher / as desired
    targetSdkVersion    = 35                // or higher / as desired
}

Also do a clean if recently upgraded.
I rolled back to 8.0.2 to resolve but I am building for API 34.

Thank you. This solution effectively resolved the issue.
